# Convergence of sequences implies closedness in a general topological space

Tags: general-topology

It can be shown that in any metric space $X$, a set $V\subseteq X$ is closed iff for all convergent sequences $\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\subseteq V$, $v_n\to v$ implies that $v\in V$.

However, I ignore wether this same result is true in a general topological space $X$. It is  easy to show that if $V$ is closed, any convergent sequence $\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\subseteq V$ satisfies that its limits are elements of $V$. Is the reciprocal implication true? If not, is there a known set of sufficient conditions (other than the topology being induced by a metric, of course) for it to be true?

Comment: I think you are looking for e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set#Equivalent_definitions

Comment: $X$ should be first countable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Sequence_in_a_topological_space